# Does normalization also help to prevend the vanish/exploding gradients?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, numpy

I am implementing my own neural network from scratch using numpy. I tested my code with the MNIST dataset and I forgot to normalize the images and my code did not work, because I got an error about a zero division. But after normalization, I did not get any error and my cost as well as my metrics were improving with time, so I thing my code is correct, but I cannot understand why I got that error before, So I remembered of the vanishing gradients problem and I wonder if that is the reason, what are your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalization is in general good for gradient descent approaches. Inputs with different scales, having the same or similar learning rates, can easily prevent learning. Specifically, in neural nets, there is also activation functions, whose derivatives are very small around small/large values. Repeated over cascaded layers, the gradients can easily become useless for practical purposes. (e.g. for images, consider using $e^{-255}$ or $e^{-1}$).

In such cases, I'd expect to see either NaN's in the outputs (because something has exploded) or the learning to visibly stop (because of vanishing gradients). However, division by zero, is indeed interesting and not what I'd expect (since the backpropagation formula doesn't involve explicit divisions).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I should have explained that the zero division error came from my cost function, which is the cross entropy cost function that uses log and np.log(0) returns this divided by zero error. After this error I printed some things and I saw NaN's in the output like you said.